# Why Batch-normalization Layer follows scale layer in caffe?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, batch-normalization

I noticed that Batch Normalization layer follows Scale layer in mobile net. It seems BN layer and scale layer are a pair.
 And Convolution layer + BN layer + Scale layer + ReLU layer works well.
So what scale layer do?
It seems caffe can't learn parameters in BN layer, so Scale layer is useful, but why?
In tensorflow doc, https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/batch_norm

> When the next layer is linear (also e.g. nn.relu), this can be
>   disabled since the scaling can be done by the next layer.

It makes me more confuse.
Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Batch Normalization does two things: First normalize with the mean and standard deviation of activations in a batch, and then perform scaling and bias to restore an appropriate range of the activations.

Caffe implemented this with two layers, the Batch Normalization layer only does the normalization part, without the scaling and bias, which can be done with the scaling layer, or might not even be needed if the next layer can also do scaling (this is what TF docs mention).

Hope this helps.